# Convert Month name and Year (Such as Jul-15) to date - Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

my column values are like this " Jul-15", "Jun-15" and etc... The data type is object.

I want to change the data type to date and the values to date. I tried

`df["Time Period"] = df["Time Period"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m-Y'))`

but it is giving me the time data `'Jul-15' does not match format '%m-Y'` .

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- Three letters month names are matched by `%b`, not `%m`.
- Two digits years are matched by `%y`, not `Y`

While you are at it, ditch `.apply` and use the vectorized [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to gain speed:

```
df['Time Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Period'], format='%b-%y')
```

See [strftime directives supported by pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html).